# Spark Service not starting using start-all.sh

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

My Hadoop cluster was running out of memory and i therefore killed all process and logged off my user. Then i tried restarting all the services using ./start-all.sh but it gives me alot of errors as below. I have search entire stack-overflow for a solution to my problem but couldnt find one.

I am getting the below error while starting spark services on cluster. The master node starts fine but i get the below errors

```
./start-all.sh 
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-db101a.out
db103a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db103a.out
db105a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db105a.out
db107a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db107a.out
db102a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db102a.out
db205a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db205a.out
db204a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db204a.out
db110a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db110a.out
db203a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db203a.out
db109a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db109a.out
db106a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db106a.out
db306a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db306a.out
db304a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db304a.out
db308a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db308a.out
db206a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db206a.out
db201a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db201a.out
db310a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db310a.out
db202a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db202a.out
db111a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db111a.out
db307a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db307a.out
db302a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db302a.out
db303a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db303a.out
db108a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db108a.out
db305a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db305a.out
db301a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db301a.out
db311a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db311a.out
db309a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db309a.out
db209a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db209a.out
db207a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db207a.out
db208a: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db208a.out
db103a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db103a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db103a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db103a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db103a.out
db105a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db105a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db105a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db105a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db105a.out
db107a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db107a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db107a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db107a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db107a.out
db102a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db102a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db102a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db102a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db102a.out
db205a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db204a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db205a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db205a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db205a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db205a.out
db204a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db204a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db204a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db204a.out
db110a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db110a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db110a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db110a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db110a.out
db203a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db109a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db203a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db203a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db203a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db203a.out
db106a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db109a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db109a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db109a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db109a.out
db106a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db106a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db106a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db106a.out
db308a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db304a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db306a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db308a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db308a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db308a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db308a.out
db304a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db304a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db304a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db304a.out
db306a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db306a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db306a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db306a.out
db206a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db206a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db206a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db206a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db206a.out
db310a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db201a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db310a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db310a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db310a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db310a.out
db201a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db201a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db201a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db201a.out
db202a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db111a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db202a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db202a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db202a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db202a.out
db111a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db111a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db111a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db111a.out
db307a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db307a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db307a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db307a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db307a.out
db302a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db302a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db302a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db302a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db302a.out
db303a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db303a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db303a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db303a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db303a.out
db108a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db108a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db108a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db108a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db108a.out
db301a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db305a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db301a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db301a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db301a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db301a.out
db305a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db305a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db305a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db305a.out
db209a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db309a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db311a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db209a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db209a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db209a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db209a.out
db309a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db309a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db309a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db309a.out
db311a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db311a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db311a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db311a.out
db207a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db207a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db207a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db207a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db207a.out
db208a: failed to launch: nice -n 0 /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://db101a:7077
db208a:      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
db208a:      at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
db208a: full log in /dbhome/dbstud1/csc571/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-dbstud1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-db208a.out
```

This is the details shown in one of the log-files

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], p$
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
```

Please comment if you need any additional information

Comment: It's likely that you have corrupted installations. Try removing/reinstalling spark on all your cluster nodes.

Comment: I actually killed all the tasks in my user by mistake and tried starting it again using start-all.sh, but it does not work anymore. I think installation is fine, but something with the configuration or permissions. This is part of my University cluster and i don't have Sudo access